# Adding attributes to the fields of RuntimeTypeModel types

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm constructing non-default `RuntimeTypeModel` for third-party library classes. However, I require some of the fields to be marked as references, just as you can do that with `[ProtoMember(N), AsReference=true]`. How can I apply those attributes to the fields of the types defined in my non-default `RuntimeTypeModel`?

UPDATE

I managed to access fields via MetaType.GetFields() and setting AsReference flag on each field individually, however I don't know if this is the right way to do what I want or maybe there is more straightforward way to do this (which should exist, imo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your edit notes, these options are available via `MetaType`, for example:

```
var metaType = model.Add(type, false);
model.AddField(1, "Foo").AsReference = true; // AddField returns the ValueMember;
                    // contrast to Add which returns the MetaType for fluent usage
```

There is also:

```
metaType.AsReferenceDefault
```

which indicates (per-type) whether a type should automatically be considered as a reference.